# Teamviewer on Centos 5.8 - No login screen on next reboot

Tags: centos

Yesterday I installed Teamviewer 7 on my Centos 5.8 desktop. After a reboot, am not able to see the login screen. Only a blue color screen is visible.

I read https://superuser.com/questions/403548/os-x-stuck-at-blue-screen-after-installing-teamviewer-host-and-rebooting?rq=1

But how do I do that on Centos?

I know that to login to Single User Mode, we need to press a key while the os boots up. And then type single in the cmd. And then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once in Single User Mode, you can try to remove TeamViewer from your system.
For example, if you have installed TeamViewer by running the `rpm -ivh teamviewer_linux.rpm` command, you can run the `rpm -e teamviewer_linux` command to uninstall it.
I don't think that the Mac OS link you've referred to can be very useful in your case.
If you peek into the `teamviewer_linux.rpm` (for example by running the command `rpm -qpl teamviewer_linux.rpm`) you won't find any "Launch Agents and Daemons", since on CentOS TeamViewer is wrapped around a Windows Emulator (wine).
By default the TeamViewer files gets installed in the `/opt/teamviewer` folder; the only exception is the startup script `/usr/bin/teamviewer7`.
Finally, the rpm post-installation script does nothing more and nothing less than create a desktop icon and add a menu entry, so I can't really understand how the TeamViewer installation could have broken your system.

Comment: Actually I had tried to add teamviewer as a launch agent and that caused the blue screen. Thanks for the reply.